# Topology and basis for topology and their size comparison

Tags: topology

I don't know the solution about this problem

Consider following topologies on R
T1: standard topology
T2: the finite complement topology
T3: its basis consists of all sets of (a, b]
T4: its basis consists of all sets of (-∞, a)
Determine, for each of the topologies, which of the others is contained in it

Comment: I think you want to ask on http://math.stackexchange.com instead.  StackOverflow is for programming questions.  However, please read the Math.SE rules and revise your question before posting it there: questions that are just a problem statement with no context or attempt get closed and deleted quickly.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question